# Disassemble DLL, do assembly changes and put it together into a new DLL

Tags: c, assembly, dll

I have a very old game written in lithtech engine. I would like to improve graphic in this game. I did it through app x32dbg and it works well.

I'm thinking about modify the default dll instead of memory injection.
My idea is disassemble the dll, do my changes and assemble it back to dll.

Will this be possible?

It is a simple dll compiled in C lang without sign.

Thanks for any answers!

Comment: how about creating a wrapper dll with the name of original one, which would load the original (under new name), inject/modify code what you want, and otherwise function as proxy/wrapper for the other calls made by the engine? I'm not sure, if this idea is doable, but if yes, it sounds as a cleaner solution to me, because you can have all the new changes in some kind of source form, and separated from original (and in case the user wants to see original, he needs just to rename the DLL files back)

Comment: It does not export function names. File's header contains only basic stuffs. Is possible to create wrapper without known the names? Thanks for idea!

Comment: It's possible in theory, but usually a full executable or DLL has some sections or blocks of instructions that disassemblers don't exactly represent in the output.  e.g. symbol export information, or instruction encodings that are longer than necessary (e.g. `push 0` encoded as `push imm32` so the value can be overwritten with something calculated at runtime.)  The self-modifying part might not happen in typical DLLs; I was thinking of Unix `.plt` dynamic-linking code.

Comment: Anyway, give [Agner Fog's objconv disassembler](http://agner.org/optimize/#objconv) a try; it can disassemble into NASM, MASM, or AT&T syntax, and puts labels on jump targets so it can re-calculate them if branch displacements change because of changing the code.  (And BTW, I think this question has been asked before, maybe for executables, but I don't want to go looking for duplicates right now.)